# MongoDB: how do I store binary array in a BSON in C++?

Tags: c++, mongodb

What's the syntax for adding binary array to a BSON with C++ driver? I'm sure it's somewhere in the docs, but can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/b836032ad24dc00d

To create a BSONObj in C++ that stores binary data, you can do something like:

```
BSONObjBuilder builder;
b.appendBinData ("fieldname", datasize, BinDataGeneral, data);
BSONObj obj = builder.obj();
```

Documentation here: http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj_builder.html#a6882df3d0e4ca68446684769bc9e4d18