# How should I insert a huge int/double array into a bson object?

Tags: c, mongodb, bson

How should I add a huge multi-dimensional (100x100) integer/double/float field to a BSON object with the C library?

The closest stackoverflow question/answer I see is for C++ ( [MongoDB: how do I store binary array in a BSON in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840824/mongodb-how-do-i-store-binary-array-in-a-bson-in-c) )

I was thinking maybe I should use bson_append_binary?  I'm not really sure how I'd do that though... I should admit that my C is pretty weak.  I'd write how I think I could convert an double[] to binary, but I really don't know how yet.

I'm not opposed to switching to C++, but if it's practical I'd prefer to stick with the C drivers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I, and the person who answered was right, it is with `bson_append_binary`.

Doing,

```
int array[] = {10,11,12};
int *array_ptr = array;
...
bson_append_binary(&b, "fld", BSON_BIN_USER, (char*)array_ptr, sizeof(array));
...
```

Then, I was able to read the array out of mongo with:

```
...
if ( bson_find( iterator, mongo_cursor_bson( cursor ), "fld" )) {
    array_ptr = (int*)bson_iterator_bin_data(iterator);
    printf(" first element: %i\n", *(array_ptr++));
    printf("second element: %i\n", *(array_ptr++));
    printf(" third element: %i\n", *array_ptr);
}
...
```

Looks simple but because my C is terrible it took me hours.  Next challenge is to figure out how to read the binary from another (e.g. PHP) client.  Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would use the bson_append_binary() function call:

[bson_append_binary() API doc](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/bson_8h.html#a9f2a39604f01c1f6337717f5c2a38aea)

So the code would look something like:

```
int[100][100] bigArray;
bson_append_binary(bsonHandle, "yourFieldName", BSON_BIN_BINARY, bigArray, sizeof(bigArray));
```

Comment: hey, thanks!  I think it has to be a char though, I was playing with this last night some more.  I'll put more in an "answer" rather than a comment.  Thanks though!

Comment: I think I read BSON_BIN_BINARY was deprecated.  That said, the [bson_binary_subtype](http://algernon.github.com/libmongo-client/group__bson__types.html#gab69c9ec1c9cdabbb2db338e58a6e55fe) at  aren't even defined in the v0.7 tag of the C client.  Looking in the .h file, I found BSON_BIN_USER rather than BSON_BINARY_SUBTYPE_USER_DEFINED